# Find Closest Value in Vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, lower-bound

What I am trying to accomplish is iterating through a vector of double values and returning the vector position of the closest possible double. I am having two issues with this.

1. When attempting to find the closest double value in the vector using `lower_bound()`, i only receive a value other than zero if I enter 1.
2. I am not sure how to use `lower_bound` to return a vector position instead of a double value.

Here is my three main files I am using with attempted code

Convert.cpp

```
double Convert::convertmVtoK(double value)
{
    double conversion = *std::lower_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value);
    cout<<"This is conversion mV to K"<<" "<< conversion;
}

double Convert::convertKtomV(double value)
{
    double conversion = *std::lower_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value);
    cout<<"This is conversion K to mV"<<" "<< conversion;
}
```

Conversion.h

```
class Convert
{
    public:
        Convert();
        virtual ~Convert();
        double convertmVtoK(double mV);
        double convertKtomV(double K);
        void readFile();

    protected:

    private:
        std::ifstream inFile;
        std::vector<double> kelvin,mV,sensitivity;
        double tempKelvin,tempmV,tempSensitivity;
};

#endif // CONVERT_H
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Convert.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>


int main()
{
    Convert convert;
    convert.readFile();
   convert.convertmVtoK(2.0);
    convert.convertKtomV(5.000);

    return 0;
}
```

Update: So I am still attempting to use lower_bound(). Here is my updated function.

```
double Convert::convertmVtoK(double value)
{
    std::vector<double>::iterator pos;

    pos = std::lower_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value);
    cout<<"This is conversion mV to K"<<" "<< kelvin[(pos-mV.begin())];
}
```

Currently the if I input a float value I am still not able to recieve the correct vector value, it either returns 0 or the [0] vector value.

Update 2: text values

```
1.4 1.644290    -12.5
1.5 1.642990    -13.6
1.6 1.641570    -14.8
1.7 1.640030    -16.0
1.8 1.638370    -17.1
1.9 1.636600    -18.3
2.0 1.634720    -19.3
2.1 1.632740    -20.3
```

Comment: lower_bound() does not return an iterator to the closest value. It returns an iterator to the first element which does not go before your value, i.e. in this case the first element `>= 5.000`.

Comment: @SidS could you recommend what to use instead of lower_bound to find the closest value in the vector?

Comment: Iterate through the whole vector, keeping track of the closest value.  Or, if you are going to do this repeatedly for the same data, sort the vector and then do a binary search.

Comment: you need to create a [MCVE]. Empty constructors and destructors, reading from file etc is completely irrelevant to your problem. Remove all that has nothing to do with the problem you are posting about and make it all a single compiling file.

Comment: @SidS ok thank you for the suggestion. So i understand how to do a binary search for an exact value, how would I go about doing a binary search for the closest value?

Comment: Keep doing the binary search until you have 2 values.

Comment: Well, observe that `lower_bound()` only works on sorted data.  So you can use it after sorting the data.  Then you look to the left and/or right of that value as needed.

Comment: @SidS I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge on this, but I appreciate the help. So if my vector is sorted already (which it is) youre saying that I can use the lower_bound method I was originally attempting instead of a binary search to find the closest value in the vector?

Comment: That would work as well.

Comment: `lower_bound()` *does* a binary search.  That's why the data has to be sorted.  You can also use `upper_bound()`.

Comment: @drescherjm ok thank you. Could you provide an example on how to return the vector value pos instead of the vector value at that posistion?

Comment: @SidS ok that makes sense that it is a binary search. I guess my issue now is that I am receiving an output of "0" if i lower_bound search a value other than 1

Comment: @SidS please stop using the comments to give solutions. Post an answer. Comments are for requesting clarifications.

Comment: @bolov, I didn't give any solutions yet.  But I now have enough information that I will post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) with a comparator that takes the distance to `value` into account:

```
// precondition: mV is not empty
double get_closest(double value) const
{
    assert(!mV.empty());
    auto it = std::min_element(mV.begin(), mV.end(), [value] (double a, double b) {
        return std::abs(value - a) < std::abs(value - b);
    });
    assert(it != mV.end());

    return *it;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Now, trying to avoid computing twice as many `std::abs(x-y)` as necessary is quite painful...

Comment: @MarcGlisse would you suggest still trying to use lower/upper_bound to reduce time complexity?

Comment: Well, this takes linear time. If the lists are long and you do many searches on the same list, of course a logarithmic approach (binary search on a sorted list) would be better. But you shoudn't care until you have measured that this is your bottleneck.

Comment: @MarcGlisse ok thank you that is why I was originally trying to use lower/upper_bound() because I don need to do many searches on this list. I for the life of me cannot figure out how to get the correct result though using SidS method or any other method ive found online for lower/upper_bound for the closest value in my vector.

Comment: @C.Mock I think your data is not properly sorted.

Answer (score 1):

lower_bound() does not return an iterator to the closest value. It returns an iterator to the first element which does not go before your value, i.e. in this case the first `element >= 5.000`

One way to solve this, if you want to use `lower_bound()` etc :

```
vector<double> v;
double d = 5.0;
auto it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), d);
if (it == v.begin())
{
    // No elements are smaller than d
    it = v.end();
}
else
{
    --it;
    // it now points to the largest element smaller than d
}

auto jt = upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), d);
if (jt == v.end())
{
    // No elements are larger than d
}
else
{
    // jt already points to the smallest element larger than d
}

auto out = it;
if (it == v.end())
{
    out = jt;
}
else if (jt != v.end())
{
    if (d - *it > *jt - d)
    {
        out = jt;
    }
}
// out now points to the value closest to d, or v.end() (if v is empty or only contains d)
```

---

The above code can be reduced to this equivalent code:

```
vector<double> v;
double d = 5.0;
auto it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), d);
if (it == v.begin())
{
    it = v.end();
}
else
{
    --it;
}
auto jt = upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), d),
     out = it;
if (it == v.end() || jt != v.end() && d - *it > *jt - d)
{
    out = jt;
}
```

---

There are more compact ways to go about this sort of problem, but this illustrates how to solve the problem at hand by using relatively simple concepts.

The time complexity of `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` is quite good, too.

Comment: Thank you! So I was successfully able to implement this withou any errors. However I am either receiving the first or last vector output only as the closest value. Trying to see if I can see where that is happening

Comment: Maybe its the first use of lower_bound here "auto it = lower_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value);" ? If i just use this line I am receiving 0 or the first vector value only.

Comment: @C.Mock, I tested the code before posting it here and it does work.  If it doesn't work for you, you're not using it correctly - or your data is not sorted in ascending order.  Other than that, I can't tell you what your error is without seeing your code - and your data.

Comment: ok that is the problem then i think is that it is in decending. Can the same formula be used except switch the upper and lower bound?

Comment: so my kelvin values are in ascending order but my voltage values are in descending. I posted an update with a snippet of the text  values.

Comment: You could use `std::reverse()` on the voltage data after reading the data in.
  Or, perhaps use `vector::rbegin()` and `vector::rend()` for data sorted in descending order, although that seems a bit messy to me.