# Find Closest Value in Vector Using lower/upper_bound()

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search, lower-bound

What I am trying to accomplish is iterating through a vector of double values and returning the vector position of the closest possible double.

When attempting to find the closest double value in the vector using `lower_bound()`, I either receive the value "0" or the "144" (the last position of my vector) no matter what double value I try to search for.

Here is my attempted code

Attempt 1:

```
double Convert::convertmVtoK(double value)
{
  std::vector<double>::iterator low,up;
  low=std::lower_bound (mV.begin(), mV.end(), value);           
  up= std::upper_bound (mV.begin(), mV.end(), value);                    

  std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- mV.begin()) << '\n';
  std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - mV.begin()) << '\n';
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
double Convert::convertmVtoK(double value)
{
    auto it = lower_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value);

    if (it == mV.begin())
    {
        it = mV.begin();
    }
    else
    {
        --it;
    }

    auto jt = upper_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value), out = it;

    if (it == mV.end() || jt != mV.end() && value - *it > *jt - value)
    {
    out = jt;
    }

    cout<<"This is conversion mV to K"<<" "<< *out;
}
```

Comment: Are your data sorted ? (mostly required to use `lower_bound`/`upper_bound`).

Comment: If it is the case, it is one of `lower_bound` and `lower_bound - 1` which is the closest.

Comment: *"I either receive the value "0" or the "144" "* You should provide input too.

Comment: Also, how difficult would it have been to write a simple 3 or 4 line [mcve] calling `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` with your results?   Isn't that how you learn and isolate the issue, and also have others have an answer ready for you almost instantly?  Why stick something into an unknown class as a method, not knowing where, when, or how that class is working within your code?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes it is sorted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Closest Value in Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056171/find-closest-value-in-vector)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it is  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. As for the results i did mention it was either "0" or the "144". Please stop commenting if youre not going to help

Comment: @C.Mock -- No, it is not complete and minimal.  [Here is a minimal example that is compilable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81bb7b4fb5737d38).  That is what any programmer who is not sure of a function would do.  Write a simple function to see where the problems may lie.  You now saying that the data is sorted, it now begs the question of whether your `Convert` object is valid.

Comment: @C.Mock: It is not complete, input is missing. `Convert` and `mV` are not declared...

Comment: BTW, your method doesn't return any value whereas it should return `double`...